Unable to configure GCP API Gateway to call cloud function using Terraform
I have been trying to configure GCP's API Gateway to talk to a Cloud Run Function. I am attempting to use Terraform as these will be fundamental components and I want to be able to easily build on them in the future. I am trying to have a secured endpoint using an API key and my desired behaviour is that the API gateway verifies the api key and then makes an unauthenticated call to the cloud function. The cloud function should be protected by using ingress only networking.
No matter what I do, following the various quick starts, documentation and thorough conversations with the GPT community, I always get a 403 error response when calling the API Gateway URL.
{"message":"PERMISSION_DENIED: API my-api-0esofolowrs06.apigateway.propane-crawler-437508-t1.cloud.goog is not enabled for the project.","code":403}
The api gateway is enabled, I have checked in the UI. I have also manually enabled my-api-0esofolowrs06.apigateway.propane-crawler-437508-t1.cloud.goog after my terraform script has run but I still get the same error.
What am I doing wrong? I can't believe I'm having such trouble setting up something I feel should be very simple.
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
    google-beta = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google-beta"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}

# Initialise Providers #########################################################################
provider "google" {
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
}

provider "google-beta" {
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
}

# Utilities ##################################################################################
# Retrieve the project number
data "google_project" "project" {
  project_id = var.project_id
}


# Create Service Accounts #####################################################################
# Service account for the gateway
resource "google_service_account" "my-gateway" {
  account_id = "my-gateway"
}

# Give the gateway permissions to invoke cloud run services
resource "google_project_iam_member" "my-gateway" {
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.my-gateway.email}"
  project = var.project_id
  role    = "roles/run.invoker"
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function_iam_member" "invoker" {
  project        = var.project_id
  location       = google_cloudfunctions2_function.default.location
  cloud_function = google_cloudfunctions2_function.default.name
  role           = "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
  member     = "allUsers"
  depends_on = [google_cloudfunctions2_function.default]
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_member" "member" {
  location = google_cloudfunctions2_function.default.location
  service  = google_cloudfunctions2_function.default.name
  role     = "roles/run.invoker"
    member   = "allUsers"
  # member     = "serviceAccount:service-${data.google_project.project.number}@gcp-sa-apigateway.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  depends_on = [google_cloudfunctions2_function.default]
}

# Cloud Function Deployment ###############################################################
resource "random_id" "default" {
  byte_length = 8
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "default" {
  name                        = "${random_id.default.hex}-gcf-source" # Every bucket name must be globally unique
  location                    = "US"
  uniform_bucket_level_access = true
}

data "archive_file" "default" {
  type        = "zip"
  output_path = "/tmp/function-source.zip"
  source_dir  = "nodejs-docs-samples/functions/helloworld/helloworldHttp"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "object" {
  name   = "function-source.zip"
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.default.name
  source = data.archive_file.default.output_path # Add path to the zipped function source code
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function" "default" {
  name        = "function-v2"
  location    = "us-central1"
  description = "a new function"

  build_config {
    runtime     = "nodejs20"
    entry_point = "helloHttp" # Set the entry point
    source {
      storage_source {
        bucket = google_storage_bucket.default.name
        object = google_storage_bucket_object.object.name
      }
    }
  }

  service_config {
    max_instance_count = 1
    available_memory   = "256M"
    timeout_seconds    = 60
    ingress_settings   = "ALLOW_INTERNAL_ONLY"
  }
}


# API Gateway Deployment ###################################################################

# Enable the API Gateway API
resource "google_project_service" "apigateway" {
  service = "apigateway.googleapis.com"
}

# Create the API
resource "google_api_gateway_api" "my-api" {
  provider   = google-beta
  api_id     = "my-api"
  depends_on = [google_project_service.apigateway]
}

resource "google_api_gateway_api_config" "my-api-config" {
  provider      = google-beta
  api           = google_api_gateway_api.my-api.api_id
  api_config_id = "my-api-config"
  gateway_config {
    backend_config {
      google_service_account = google_service_account.my-gateway.email
    }
  }
  openapi_documents {
    document {
      path = "openapi.yaml"
      contents = base64encode(templatefile("${path.module}/openapi.yaml.tmpl", {
        backend_address       = google_cloudfunctions2_function.default.service_config[0].uri
        service_account_email = "service-${data.google_project.project.number}@gcp-sa-apigateway.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      }))
    }
  }

  depends_on = [google_cloudfunctions2_function.default]
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

# Create the Gateway
resource "google_api_gateway_gateway" "gateway" {
  provider   = google-beta
  gateway_id = "my-api-gateway"
  api_config = google_api_gateway_api_config.my-api-config.id
  depends_on = [
    google_api_gateway_api_config.my-api-config,
    google_cloudfunctions2_function.default
  ]
}



# Outputs ##################################################################################

output "function_uri" {
  value = "Function - [${google_cloudfunctions2_function.default.service_config[0].uri}]"
}

output "api_gateway_url" {
  value = "Gateway - [https://${google_api_gateway_gateway.gateway.default_hostname}]"
}

output "pipeline_api_id" {
  value = "Pipeline API ID - [${google_api_gateway_api.my-api.id}]"
}


The OpenAPI Spec for the gateway is:
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: my-api API for all  operations
  description: API for all operations on Cloud Functions
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /hello:
    get:
      summary: Greet a user
      operationId: hello
      x-google-backend:
        address: "${backend_address}" # Set to the cloud function url
        path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS              
      security:
      - api_key: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
securityDefinitions:
  # This section configures basic authentication with an API key.
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "key"
    in: "query"

So far I have tried numerous differing configurations to make this work. I've tried adding auth to the cloud function and configuring service account access and JWT authentication. I've looked at the logs for the requests between the services. I've Enabled all necessary APIs (Cloud Functions,  Cloud Run (Admin API), Cloud Build, Artifact Registry, Cloud Storage, API Gateway, Service Control, api keys) through the UI.

you might like to check - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237250997

Enable the API service via Terraform, try this with the google_project_service resource:
resource "google_project_service" "apigateway" {
 project = var.project_id
 service = google_api_gateway_api.apigateway.managed_service

timeouts {
   create = "30m"
   update = "40m"
 }

 disable_dependent_services = true
}


Here are the other thing that you may consider to proceed with configurations:

If you are using multiple Google accounts, check the permission and credentials stored at (For Linux and macOS users)

$HOME/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json

You can enable User Application Default Credentials (ADCs) by running the command in cloud shell

gcloud auth application-default login


This answer from @ChristianOConnor related to your question might help you as well.


